# Old project don't show current windows in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

When i open "test" project then "Loop" project gone from window. But I want see my all project in one windows.

[image: project]

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/eclipse.html):

> The first thing you'll notice when launching IntelliJ IDEA is that it has no workspace concept. This means that you can work with only one project at a time.

It may well be the case  that you don't need to switch projects in IntelliJ, since you could create an IntelliJ project which contains multiple modules. However, if you are dealing with distinct projects here then it is possible to switch between currently open projects in IntelliJ using keystrokes or a menu. From [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/switching-between-projects.html):

> To switch between the currently opened projects, do one of the following
>
> On the main menu, choose Window | Next Project Window/Previous Project Window.
>
> Press ⌘ `or ⇧⌘`.
>
> On the main menu, point to Window, and then select the name of the desired project.

Answer (score 0):

For what I know, you can't get multiple projects into one window with JetStorm IDEs.

You can make them in multiple windows with different projects. Or, you can just make a project and add the projects in it.

Comment: alt-tab is his friend here :)

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ can indeed only open one project at a time - but you can easily open (and alt-tab) between projects.

If you have 2 projects that are dependent or closely related, you can look at a form of *project modularisation*.

A popular framework is `maven`, based on the *project object model* (pom.xml) specification.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

When you have a multi-module maven project in intellij, you can view all modules in the project view (tree based configuration).